# Using Microsoft Outlook API with C# to list calendars and add events

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar

I have found some Microsoft Resources about how to use the REST API to connect to an Outlook account. The sample tutorial they provided got me to create a WPF project and register an app with the Outlook Developer centre.

So I have done all of that and can connect to Outlook. It shows the content screen where the user must allow access. All good.

But I don't want to use WPF. Ideally I want to write a C# .NET DLL component what with communicate with the Outlook API so that I can specifically:

- List Calendars
- Add events to calendar
- Delete events from calendar

I understand that I need to use the [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) library but I can't find out how to use this with C# .NET.

I am familiar with the Google Calendar API and have written a **VB. NET**  command line utility that does the same things. So I was hoping to do things similarly.

The WPF tutorial stops at the "connect" stage so I am at a loss as to how to proceed. And the other example is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial

That shows you how to write a utility with **ASP.NET MVC Web app** to get Outlook mail, calendar, and contacts. But again, I am confused as to how to do what I want with C#.NET DLL.

If it is possible to using the Microsoft.Graph library from C# DLL to list the calendars etc. I would appreciate guidance.

If there is a more direct resource I should point this question to then I would be more than happy to do so.

Thank you.

PS. Please note that I am referring to the online Outlook system and not the Microsoft Outlook on a user PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of C# examples using the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK [available on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=sample%20user%3Amicrosoftgraph&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93). There is a Console App example included in that list: [ConsoleApp-DeltaQuery-DotNet-Sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/ConsoleApp-DeltaQuery-DotNet-Sample).

Comment: I am sorry but when I look at that sample I just don't understand it. I found the Google v3  API much easier to manage that this. But it is only because I can't grasp the whole concept just yet.

Comment: Your comments on my other question have helped me greatly. Perhaps you can collate some of your comments into a answer on the other question? Then we can close this one?

Answer (score 0):

This sample demonstrates how to use the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK to access data in Office 365 from ASP.NET Core apps.

[git code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-aspnet-core/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file)