# Using Microsoft.Graph to list calendars with C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting myself in a real pickle here. :( I just don't understand how to transfer what I see here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_calendars

Into the context of my C# Console Application.

I did this much:

```
//Set the scope for API call to user.read
string[] _scopes = new string[] { "user.read",  "calendars.read" };
```

And confirm that when I sign in it does ask for access to users calendar.

But I don't know where to go from here. I have this in the sample code:

```
   private void DisplayBasicTokenInfo(AuthenticationResult authResult)
    {
        string strTokenInfoText = "";
        if (authResult != null)
        {
            strTokenInfoText += $"Name: {authResult.User.Name}" + Environment.NewLine;
            strTokenInfoText += $"Username: {authResult.User.DisplayableId}" + Environment.NewLine;
            strTokenInfoText += $"Token Expires: {authResult.ExpiresOn.ToLocalTime()}" + Environment.NewLine;
            strTokenInfoText += $"Access Token: {authResult.AccessToken}" + Environment.NewLine;
            Console.WriteLine(strTokenInfoText);
        }
    }
```

But there is nothing evidently I can use from there to get at the list of calendars.

I asked a similar question here with no answers, but I made more progress since then:

[Using Microsoft Outlook API with C# to list calendars and add events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653433/using-microsoft-outlook-api-with-c-sharp-to-list-calendars-and-add-events)

## Update

I adjusted my method like this:

```
public async Task AquireToken()
{
    AuthenticationResult authResult = null;

    try
    {
        if (authResult == null)
        {
            authResult = await Program.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_scopes, Program.PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
    {
        // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

        try
        {
            authResult = await Program.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(_scopes);
        }
        catch (MsalException msalex)
        {
            strResultsText = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        strResultsText = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
    }

    if (authResult != null)
    {
        strResultsText = await GetHttpContentWithToken(_graphAPIEndpoint, authResult.AccessToken);

        DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult);

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
             new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                 (requestMessage) =>
                 {
                     // Append the access token to the request.
                     requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                     return Task.FromResult(0);
                 }));

        SignOut();
        if (strResultsText != "")
            Console.WriteLine(strResultsText);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I added this bit of code:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
     new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
         (requestMessage) =>
         {
             // Append the access token to the request.
             requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
             return Task.FromResult(0);
         }));
```

I put a break point on `SignOut` but can't get it to work.

I was hoping to be able to use `graphClient.me.Calendars`.

Confused.

## Update

I have tried looking at the read me. Perhaps I am just doing things in the wrong places? But when I put a breakpoint:

[image: Breakpoint]

It is not as I expect.

## Update 2

I adjusted my code like this:

```
   if (authResult != null)
    {
        strResultsText = await GetHttpContentWithToken(_graphAPIEndpoint, authResult.AccessToken);

        DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult);

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                 new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                     (requestMessage) =>
                     {
                         // Append the access token to the request.
                         requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                         return Task.FromResult(0);
                     }));

        var calendars = await graphClient
                             .Me
                             .Calendars
                             .Request()
                             .GetAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(calendars.Count.ToString());
        List<Calendar> listCalendars = calendars.ToList();
        foreach(Calendar oCalendar in listCalendars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(oCalendar.Name);
        }
        SignOut();
        if (strResultsText != "")
            Console.WriteLine(strResultsText);
    }
```

With a breakpoint on `SignOut` even though the watch list says nothing is there, in my console window I have:

[image: Console Output]

So it seems that it works OK. I guess I just have to adjust the logic of my code perhaps and get the `AquireToken` method to just return the Token and take it from there. I will play more tomorrow.

## Update 3

Thanks to your comments I go this to work:

```
public async Task BuildCalendarsList()
{
    if (_AuthResult == null)
        return;

    try
    {
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                 new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                     (requestMessage) =>
                     {
                         // Append the access token to the request.
                         requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", _AuthResult.AccessToken);
                         return Task.FromResult(0);
                     }));

        var calendars = await graphClient
                             .Me
                             .Calendars
                             .Request()
                             .GetAsync();

        Console.WriteLine($"Number of calendars: {calendars.Count}");

        _ListCalendars = calendars.ToList();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _ListCalendars = null;
        Console.WriteLine($"Error BuildCalendarsList: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

public void DisplayCalendarsList()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Calendar oCalendar in _ListCalendars)
        {
            string strCalendarInfo = $"Calendar Name: {oCalendar.Name}";
            strCalendarInfo += $" Calendar Id: {oCalendar.Id}";
            Console.WriteLine(strCalendarInfo);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error DisplayCalendarsList: {ex.Message}");
    }
 }
```

Comment: All of your code here is related to authentication, not to retrieving a list of calendars. Are you receiving an error authenticating?

Comment: I can get the pop up screen and user accepts. I can display user token info. But I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: You'll need to make calls into Graph API to request the list of calendars. You can find the complete documentation at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/

Comment: That is what I tried to do with the second GraphClientService call.

Comment: Graph and Auth are two different things. Auth is about getting a token that you then supply to an API like Graph, Skype, Outlook etc.

Comment: Look at the code after DisplayBasicTokenInfo. That was supposed to make a graph client. I put breakpoint on signout and it doesn't work.

Comment: What error are you getting and what did you expect it to do? I'm not seeing any calls into the API, just an instance of a GraphClient  object.

Comment: I expected the breakpoint to stop on signout. I expected to be able to view the graph client in watch variable.

Comment: If it isn't hitting the breakpoint, then it implies `authResult` is `null`.

Comment: Have you followed these readme instructions: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I have just looked and it is helpful. I will have to re-read. I have updated my question. I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of others, this is how I get it to work:

```
public bool InitAuthenticatedClientAsync()
{
    bool bSuccess = true;

    _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
                    // See: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-3-released#acquiring-a-token-also-got-simpler
                    _AuthResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(_Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
                {
                    // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                    try
                    {
                        // See: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-3-released#acquiring-a-token-also-got-simpler
                        _AuthResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(_Scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                    }
                    catch (MsalException msalex)
                    {
                        SimpleLog.Log(msalex);
                        Console.WriteLine("GetAuthenticatedClientAsync: Acquire token error. See log.");
                        bSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    SimpleLog.Log(ex);
                    Console.WriteLine("GetAuthenticatedClientAsync: Acquire token silently error. See log.");
                    bSuccess = false;
                }

                if(bSuccess)
                {
                    // Append the access token to the request.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", _AuthResult.AccessToken);

                    // Get event times in the current time zone.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"" + TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id + "\"");
                }
            }));

    return bSuccess;
}

public async Task<bool> BuildCalendarsList()
{
    bool bSuccess = true;

    if (_graphClient == null)
        return false;

    try
    {
        var calendars = await _graphClient
                             .Me
                             .Calendars
                             .Request()
                             .GetAsync();


        foreach (Calendar oCalendar in calendars)
        {
            _CalendarInfo.AddCalendarEntry(oCalendar.Name, oCalendar.Id);
        }

        bSuccess = SaveCalendarInfo();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
        Console.WriteLine("BuildCalendarsList: See error log.");
        bSuccess = false;
    }

    return bSuccess;
}
```